# Eq. (7.12) in Elements of Statistical Learning

Tags: regression, least-squares, bias-variance-tradeoff, decomposition

I'm looking the snippet below from ESL. I'm a hard time deriving the variance term (last term in Eq. 7.12).

I started with
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{N}\sum_i ||h(x_i)||^2\sigma^2 \\
    = \frac{1}{N}\sigma^2\sum_i ||h(x_i)||^2 \\
    = \frac{1}{N} \sigma^2 \sum_i x_i^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_i\\
\end{align}

If I compare my last expression and their's it would seem the summation is equal to $p$. Assuming my above steps are correct, I can't see how this simplifies to $p$.

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The key step is to note that the sum is the trace of the hat matrix, i.e.
$$
\sum_i x_i^T(X^TX)^{-1}x_i = \text{tr}\left(X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\right) \\
= \text{tr}((X^TX)^{-1}X^TX) = \text{tr}(I_p) = p.
$$